# VMWARE - Migration went wrong - failure

Tags: migration, vmware, virtualization, snapshot

Need your help:

Short story, I've tried to migrate a ESXI VM to a new ESXI server and make an huge mistake, instead of copy the VM I move it to a shared folder, NFS, when trying to add inventory it adds, but don't started. I've successfully create the vmx file and VM it worked, but now I have another problem, the VM has more then 1 year old, so it's missing the snapshot. Now start's my doubts and can't figure out after many hours...  I've added the snapshot file and the vm but can't figure it out how to put it to work.

This is a picture of the files structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbzdX.png)

The image has two parts the, first it the VM working folder and the other folder "ZZ Temp", has the snapshot and the vm?. I had to create this folder because could not copy them inside the VM already exist also I've copy "Windows Server 2008 R2-000001-delta.vmdk" to the VM It later let me to do so...

Conclusion this is all a mess and can't figure it out how to reaseamble this, can someone help me to do this.

1- Can I copy the files to the old server and reassemble, but I have the same issue it don't let me copy all the files to the VM folder.

2-How can I know if the 300GB "Windows Server 2008 R2-flat.vmdk" file is the base file server? 
Do I need it or I just need this 2 from ZZ Temp folder "Windows Server 2008 R2-flat.vmdk","Windows Server 2008 R2-000001-delta.vmdk"

I'm completely lost need your guidance.